# Windows Media Player mute sound by default when launching the program

Tags: windows-10, audio, windows-media-player

When I open any file on Windows Media Player, it plays with the sound muted. I can turn on the sound if I click on the sound button next to the volume slider. But if I exit and open again the program, the sound will be muted again. How i can can turn on the sound by default when launching the program?

[image: picture of the bug]

Comment: Have you tried Repairing and/or Reinstalling Windows Media Player?

Comment: Restore Windows 10 Media Player with Powershell.    ......   https://winaero.com/restore-windows-media-player-windows-10/

Comment: There is no options of Repairing this component. Only delete.

Comment: I left you a link to restore WMP with Powershell.

Comment: Problem not fixed after delete and restore. Other options, such as repeating restored too.

Comment: Try Groove Music instead.   ....   https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-reinstall-groove-music-app-in-windows-10/#:~:text=Clicking%20the%20Install%20button%20will,Good%20luck!

Comment: Right after opening Windows Media Player, could you check if it's muted in Volume Mixer? (right-click on the speaker icon in the taskbar and select `Open Volume mixer`). The Volume Mixer remembers these per-application volume settings, even when the application is closed and reopened.